# Verificar qual dos 'guards' está loggedin

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Eu tenho uma aplicação laravel 5.2, com multiautenticação, os guards configurados em `config/auth.php` são:

```
...
'admin' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'admin',
],
'user' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'user',
],
...
```

Ou seja `admin` e `user`.

O meu problema é na view, pois estes dois guards quando loggedin partilham algumas mesmas views, aí é que é gerado o problema:

```
Olá {{Auth::guard('admin')->user()->name}}
```

Neste caso o guard correspondente está hardcoded para ser sempre o `admin` (dando erro caso seja o guard `user` que esteja loggedin), depois de alguma pesquisa não encontrei nada de me indicasse a solução, ou seja, de saber se o guard que está loggedin é `user` ou `admin`, dessa maneira escusava de outra view igual só com essa alteração. EX de solução:

```
Olá {{Auth::guard(<GUARD QUE ESTEJA LOGIN>)->user()->name}}
```

PS: Sei que daria indo pelo segmento do url correspondente ao guard, ex: `www.site.com/pt/user/dasboard`, neste caso seria o segmento 2, mas perdia-se um da escalabilidade da app pois nada garante que no futuro o segmento correspondente do url continue a ser o 2.

Answer (score 4):

Cara, já pensou nisso:

```
$guard    = $this->getGuard();
$provider = $guard->getProvider();
Auth::guard($provider)->get()->name;
```

Senão, algo que você pode fazer:

```
if(Auth::guard('admin')->check()){
   Auth::guard('admin')->admin()->name;
}
elseif(Auth::guard('user')->check()){
   Auth::guard('user')->user()->name;
}
```

Comment: Obgado pela resposta Diego, mas isso ia tirar escalabilidade à app, no futuro teria de mexer nisso se os guards não fossem os mesmos... Queria saber o guard loggedin independentemente do nome que possa ter. O facto de ter de escrever o nome do guard é que estou a tentar evitar. Daria um voto por tentar ajudar mas só posso amanha, já gastei os meus votos hoje mas não me vou esquecer

Comment: Mas o primeiro código da minha resposta pega o Guard Logged. Não é isso que deseja ? Não fixar um, mas sei pegar o que está na ativa ?

Comment: Nop, fazendo `dd($this->getGuard());` no controller dá: `Method [getGuard] does not exist.` Também perguntei no SOen mas sem sucesso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999725/checking-which-guard-is-loggedin/39002084?noredirect=1#comment65357513_39002084

Comment: Eu alterei o código. Não está mais assim.

Comment: Sim, mas o problema é `$this->getGuard();` dá o erro que escrevi

Comment: Entendi. Vou pensar mais nisso.